# Repeatedly combining multiple fields into one in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, append

I have a huge a table of 211 columns. I have a set of columns that I want to "stack" into one. I'm not very good at explaining this in words so hope this helps making it clearer:

Example:

```
Column Name: | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 |
Value      : | AA | BB | CC | AA | EE | DD | 11 | 22 |
```

I want to make another table by combining: C1 with C4, C2 with C5, C3 with C6 and keeping C7 and C8 for each rows. This will be the end result:

```
Column Name: | C1 | C2 | C3 | C7 | C8 |
Value      : | AA | BB | CC | 11 | 22 |
Value      : | AA | EE | DD | 11 | 22 |
```

Is there a good way of doing this using sql commands? Keep in mind that this is a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish, I actually have to combine 20 sets of 5 columns into one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a union query:

```
Select C1 As C1_C4, C2 As C2_C5, C3 As C3_C6, C7, C8
From YourTable
Union All
Select C4 As C1_C4, C5 As C2_C5, C6 As C3_C6, C7, C8
From YourTable
```

Comment: The query makes good sense but I'm not sure why it asks for a parameter value of C1 when I run it. When I entered a value, it overwrites the whole C1_C4 with that value.

Comment: It will ask for C1 if your table doesn't have a field with that name.